# Howto use the Titanium for developing the IPhone application?

Tags: iphone

I want to use the titanium for developing the iphone applications.Mainly how to develop the apps using titanium.What is the editor for write the code.And what are the adv antages of titanium compared to ios.please tell me

Comment: Please go through old post.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4072239/is-titanium-appcelerator-worth-it-for-developing-camera-based-application-on-ipad which clearly explains the use of titanium for development

Answer (score 0):

Well Titanium comes with Aptana as it's standard code-editor. It's a pretty good editor, has good syntax highlighting and auto-completion.

There are currently two versions: Aptana Studio (standalone) and **[Titanium Studio](http://www.appcelerator.com/products/titanium-studio/)** which includes Aptana Studio + the Titanium files. You may want to get the second one.

The **Advantages** of using Titanium are clearly Portability and ease of use. You can port your application to various Mobile Platforms pretty fast and only need some knowledge  of HTML, CSS and JavaScript.

The **Disadvantages** are that you'll have a bunch of constraints in your development and you may not be able to have access to the full native functionality of the iOS environment.