# Overlays on top of the camera screen

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile

I was trying to find the way to add some overlays on top of the camera screen for a Titanium's app. Looking through StackOverflow I've came across this post:

[Is Titanium appcelerator worth it for developing camera based application on ipad, iphone and android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4072239/is-titanium-appcelerator-worth-it-for-developing-camera-based-application-on-ipa)

where Tim Rosenblatt said that it was posible. I was wondering if someone can point me some links where I can find some documentation to do that.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

```
var overlay = Ti.UI.createView({ top: 20, right: 20, height: 50, left: 20 });
Ti.Media.showCamera({
    overlay: overlay
});
```

You can see the rest of the arguments you can pass to showCamera here:

http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/2.1/index.html#!/api/CameraOptionsType

You'll probably want "showControls: false", plus "success: function() {...}", error, and cancel.

Comment: Thank you Dawson Toth, I've already tried that. The problem I've got is that I'm developing for Android and although the overlay shows on top of the camera view, there are no buttons to take the picture :(.

Comment: Have you tried adding a button and then calling Ti.Media.takePicture() when it is clicked?

Answer (score 0):

This is the link of the api docs where you can find all the properties of (UI/Network/Phone Properties) which you can in your app
http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/2.1/index.html#!/api

this second link refer to kitchen sink app. It demonstrate all the components in the Titanium DOC for refernece. Its free you can download it and install it and see the code
https://github.com/appcelerator/KitchenSink

Hope it helps

Comment: You might condense this answer down to simply "RTFM: http://docs.appcelerator.com/".